# how to check if username already exists in codeigniter my error

Tags: codeigniter

My controler cod is:

```
function register()
    {


        if(isset($_POST['register'])){

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
         // 
            if($this->form_validation->run () == true){
                echo 'Form Validate';

                $data = array(
                    'username'=>$_POST['username'],
                    'email'=>$_POST['email'],
                    'password'=>strtoupper(hash('whirlpool',$_POST['password']))
                    );

                $this->db->insert('accounts',$data);
                $this->load->model("usuarios_model");
                if($this->usuarios_model->check_user_exist($data['username'])){
    echo "already user exist";
  }{
    $this->db->insert('accounts',$data);
    redirect("painel/index");
   }

            }

        }
        $this->load->view("painel/register");
    }
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

It registers an user even though the username already exists.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Can you post the code here please ?

Comment: You have to check existence before you insert data.

Comment: i post my code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `is_unique` rule in your form_validation library.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|is_unique[table.column]');
```

Comment: Yes, if it is not true, it will return an error if you set flashdata.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in your model in where condition it will be small later of username but you used Username.

use this code in your model.

```
function check_user_exist($username){
     $this->db->wehre('username',$username);
     $this-db->from('accounts');
     $query= $this->db->get();
     if($query->num_rows() > 0){
      return true;
      }else{
         return false;
         }
      }
```

and also controller data insert after user check:

```
if($this->usuarios_model->check_user_exist($data['username'])){
    echo "already user exist";
  }{
    $this->db->insert('accounts',$data);
    redirect("painel/index");
   }
```

Comment: Error: http://prntscr.com/fzbhzr  http://prntscr.com/fzbid0 It continues to insert a user that already exists :(

Comment: I have edited my solution. please add this code in your controller

Comment: give me your controller code then I can re write because I can't re write on the screen shot. but I think don't need to share controller code the problem will be solved if you using in the controller code

Comment: If your problem is solved then please approved my solution according to StackOverflow rules.

Comment: I am not able to post my codes here follow the link of my codes that I posted on the site >>>> https://pastebin.com/NTT1i375

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using call_back function in validation. [From Codeigniter Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods)

**Controller**

```
function register() {
  if ($this->input->post('register')) {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|callback_checkUserName');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
  // 
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
      $data = array(
          'username '=> $this->input->post('username'),
          'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
          'password' => strtoupper(hash('whirlpool', $this->input->post('password')))
      );

      $this->db->insert('accounts',$data);
      echo 'success';
      exit();
    } else {
      echo validation_errors(); die; // check errors
    }
  }
  $this->load->view("painel/register");     
}

// call back validate function
function checkUserName($userName){
  if ($this->usuarios_model->checkUserexist($userName) == false) {
    return true;
  } else {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('checkUserName', 'This userName already exist!');
    return false;
  }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
function checkUserexist($userName) {
  $this->db->where('username', $userName);
  $this-db->from('accounts');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false; 
}
```

Comment: Nice, The only problem he is not registering now.

Answer (score 0):

This my code which I used in one of my projects replace the words with your code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('companyname','Company Name','trim|required|callback_companyname_exist');
```

Here is above callback function:

```
function companyname_exist($str) {
    $this->db->where('company_name', $str);
    $this->db->where('user_type','Shop');
    $prod = $this->db->get('grs_user');

    if ($prod->row()) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('companyname_exist', 'This Company name is already Available.');
        return FALSE;
    } else
    return TRUE;
}
```

You can used this for already register email check also.